Help recovering RAID 5 array while missing 1 drive
So, I had a m/b crash on one of my systems.  It also took out my O/S drive (22.04).  My data was on a RAID 5 mdadm array of 4 14tb drives.
I've got a new m/b & O/S ssd. I installed 24.04 and then connected the array drives to add the array to my system.
But when I connect my data drives to my system, 1 drive isn't responding.  How do I bring the array into my new system with only 3 of the 4 drives available.  Is it just the normal mdadm method?  Will 24.04 add an array thats missing a drive.
(Obviously, I'm going to replace the dead drive, but still).
Old system is 22.04, drives are 14tb ironwolf pro.
Help will be greatly appreciated.

Yeah. If you ever want to see my projects finished, one of these days, you should unlock my HDD.

This question is similar to: Software raid - mdadm - re-find my array. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For more specific device more details would be required. You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details; no clue as to when (product & release) it was created & what you're trying to use now etc...

I've edited the question.   It's not even close to the 'find my array' question.  I know how to add it, but I'm missing one of the drives in the set, so I'm not sure how to add a degraded array.
